# tranpose of multidimension with permute the axes

Tags: python, numpy, transpose

For higher dimensional arrays, transpose will accept a tuple of axis numbers to permute the axes (for extra mind bending):

```
In [115]: arr = np.arange(16).reshape((2, 2, 4))

In [116]: arr
Out[116]:

array([[[ 0, 1, 2, 3],
[ 4, 5, 6, 7]],
[[ 8, 9, 10, 11],
[12, 13, 14, 15]]])

In [117]: arr.transpose((1, 0, 2))
Out[117]:

array([[[ 0, 1, 2, 3],
[ 8, 9, 10, 11]],
[[ 4, 5, 6, 7],
[12, 13, 14, 15]]])
```

I am trying to understand how above output is generated for transpose((1, 0, 2). I am not able to understand what is meant is permute the axes? Request to explain in layman terms and how above output is generated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default transpose is to reverse the axes, so an `A x B` matrix becomes `B x A`.  For 3D, the default would be to transpose `A x B x C` to `C x B x A`.

In your example, `transpose(1, 0, 2)`, it will transpose `A x B x C` to `B x A x C`.  That's because the default 3D transpose is `(2, 1, 0)`, but you have `(1, 0, 2)` which simply swaps the first two axes.

When you are experimenting, it may be more clear if you use an example array of shape `2 x 3 x 4` or some other combination which has no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Transposing a matrix is essentially switching the order of your dimensions, e.g.: `arr.transpose()` is in this case equal to `arr.transpose((2,1,0))`.

On the other hand, if you wish to select the order of your dimensions by hand, you will preserve the original order (i.e. don't change anything) by transposing with `arr.transpose((0,1,2))`.

In your example you leave the last dimension (2) of your array, e.g. `[0,1,2,3]`, unchanged. However, you switch the first two (0 and 1), thus elements at `arr[0,0,0:4]` will still be there, but the contents of `arr[1,0,0:4]` now appear at `arr[0,1,0:4]` after transposing:

```
In[]: t_arr = arr.transpose((1,0,2))
In[]: arr[0,0,0:4] == t_arr[0,0,0:4]
Out[]: 
array([ True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In[]: arr[0,1,0:4] == t_arr[1,0,0:4]   # indices #0,1,0-3 and #1,0,0-3 respectively
Out[]: 
array([ True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

This is also what you expect when transposing a multidimensional matrix. The axes are swapped in a way, so that the elements are located at almost the same indices as before, just with the swapped order, i.e.:

```
arr[x,y,z] == arr.transpose()[z,y,x]           # True
arr[x,y,z] == arr.transpose((1,0,2))[y,x,z]    # True (your case)
```

Comment: I guess @JohnZwinck was faster, but I'll leave it as different ways of expressing it may be useful =)

Comment: thanks for clarification. But I didn't understand how rows are swapped. and alos what do you mean by  indices #0,0,0-3

Comment: Thanks for your remarks, I included two examples to clarify, what I meant by those indices and how the swapping 'occurs'.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an array and its transpose:

```
arr = np.arange(24).reshape((2, 3, 4))
arrt = arr.transpose((1, 0, 2))
```

By default `transpose` just reverses the order of dimensions. The particular transpose command above swaps the first two dimensions but leaves the last dimension untouched. Let's verify in a few examples:

```
print(arr.shape)
# (2, 3, 4)

print(arrt.shape)
# (3, 2, 4)

# the last dimension is the same in both arrays
print(arr[0, 0, :])
# [0 1 2 3]
print(arrt[0, 0, :])
# [0 1 2 3]

print(arr[:, 0, 0])  # what was before the first dimension
# [ 0 12]
print(arrt[0, :, 0])  # is now the second dimension
# [ 0 12]

# the first two dimensions are swapped - the submatrix is transposed
print(arr[:, :, 0])
# [[ 0  4  8]
#  [12 16 20]]
print(arrt[:, :, 0])
# [[ 0 12]
#  [ 4 16]
#  [ 8 20]]
```